# error calling api rest between two java applications

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a java application that consumes resources from another java application.
All calls work with the exception of one that uploads files.
I have received a serialization error.
Here is the code for the two applications.

Client

```
@Override
public String uploadchamado(MultipartFile attachment) throws IOException {

    class Filecall {

        private MultipartFile arquivo;
        private String descricao;
        public MultipartFile getArquivo() {
            return arquivo;
        }
        public void setArquivo(MultipartFile arquivo) {
            this.arquivo = arquivo;
        }
        public String getDescricao() {
            return descricao;
        }
        public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
            this.descricao = descricao;
        }
    }

CallUser callUser = getToken();

Filecall myFile = new Filecall();
myFile.setArquivo(attachment);
myFile.setDescricao("teste");

HttpHeaders hds = getHeaders(callUser.getAccess_token());
hds.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        hds.add("Cookie", atendimentoToken);

HttpEntity<Filecall> headers = new HttpEntity<>(myFile,hds);

ResponseEntity<CallAttachamentDTO> response = new RestTemplate().exchange(
    atendimentoApiurl + "atividades-chamado/anexos" , HttpMethod.POST, headers, 
    CallAttachamentDTO.class);
   
return "Concluido";
}
```

Server Applicatio

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class AnexoAtividadeChamadoInput {

    @NotNull
    @FileSize(max = "100MB", message = "file-size-100MB")
    private MultipartFile arquivo;

    private String descricao;
}
```

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/anexos", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_PESQUISAR_CHAMADO') or hasAuthority('ROLE_CLIENTE_EXTERNO_INTERAGIR_CHAMADO')")
    public Anexo uploadAnexos(@Valid AnexoAtividadeChamadoInput anexoInput) throws IOException {
             return atividadeChamadoService.enviarAnexoParaAmazon(anexoInput);
    }
```

Comment: you need to post the complete error call stack

Comment: serializer error- the server application does not recognize the request pattern.